# Align Select And input Text Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to align a combo and an input text with ionic2.

When i use `ion-item` inside a `ion-grid`, it always occupies 50% of the page, without respecting the configured size.

Any idea how to do this?

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-30>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="type">
            <ion-option value="work">work</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="home">home</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="cel">cel</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
     <ion-col width-70>
      <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" clearInput placeholder="Phone"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BwdCrwECIXV6krWZBCzl?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you can see in [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid) these are the values you can use to set the *width* of the columns:

```
Explicit Column Percentage Attributes
width-10        10%
width-20        20%
width-25        25%
width-33        33.3333%
width-50        50%
width-67        66.6666%
width-75        75%
width-80        80%
width-90        90%
```

That's why if you try to use `width-30` or `width-70`, nothing will change. Instead, you can align those two fields by using `width-33` and `width-67` like you can see in [this working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9X8scg?p=preview).

There, if you inspect the `ion-col` element in the browser, you'll see this style rule being applied:

```
ion-col[width-33], ion-col[width-34] {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.3333%;
    max-width: 33.3333%;
}
```

And

```
ion-col[width-66], ion-col[width-67] {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
    flex: 0 0 66.6666%;
    max-width: 66.6666%;
}
```

Which was not happening with `width-30` and `width-70`.

Comment: Thanks. Perfect answer

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving ion-item as the parent tag for ion-row

```
<ion-item>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-30>

          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="type">
            <ion-option value="work">work</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="home">home</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="cel">cel</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
     <ion-col width-70>
      <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" clearInput placeholder="Phone"></ion-input>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-item>
```